# How prove this inequality with $x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n}=n$

Tags: inequality

Let $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n}>0$,and $x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n}=n$,show that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{i}{1+x_{i}+x^2_{i}+\cdots+x^{i-1}_{i}}\le\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{i+1}{1+x_{i}+x^2_{i}+\cdots+x^i_{i}}\tag{1}$$

I try prove following
$$\dfrac{i}{1+x_{i}+x^2_{i}+\cdots+x^{i-1}_{i}}\le\dfrac{i+1}{1+x_{i}+x^2_{i}+\cdots+x^i_{i}}$$
$$\Longrightarrow \dfrac{i(1+x_{i}+x^2_{i}+\cdots+x^i_{i})-(i+1)(1+x_{i}+\cdots+x^{i-1}_{i})}{(1+x_{i}+x^2_{i}+\cdots+x^{i-1}_{i})(1+x_{i}+x^2_{i}+\cdots+x^i_{i})}\le 0$$
or
$$\dfrac{ix^i_{i}-(1+x_{i}+\cdots+x^{i-1}_{i})}{(1+x_{i}+x^2_{i}+\cdots+x^{i-1}_{i})(1+x_{i}+x^2_{i}+\cdots+x^i_{i})}\le 0$$
it seem this numerator not alway hold,$ix^i_{i}-(1+x_{i}+\cdots+x^{i-1}_{i})\le 0$?
so this inequality $(1)$ How to prove it? maybe use induction to prove? Thanks

Comment: There's a category error in this question, $x_1 + \cdots + x_n = n$ makes no sense, you're mixing indices and variable values. What actually is $n$?

Comment: @Thomas Why does $x_1+x_2=2$ make no sense?